# Thinktecture EmbeddedSTS causing duplicate HTTP requests

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies, adfs, claims, thinktecture

I need some help in resolving a strange behavior I came across while using Thinktectures Embedded STS locally in my ASP.net MVC application. I don’t see this issue on the server using ADFS.

**The issue is**
After I sign in into the application, most of the HTTP calls from then on are getting called twice.
The first HTTP request goes without the FedAuth cookie to which the server responds with a status code of 302 (redirect) and another request to the same URL is made but this time with the Fedauth cookie. I'm trying to understand what is causing the browser to send the first request without the FedAuth cookie and also why the server redirects to the same URL?

I also need help in understanding how the EmbeddedSTS URL gets resolved. I went through the code on Github but it is not very clear to me how the EmbeddedSTS url is resolved.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue on my own.
This issue is related to cookie paths being case sensitive. My virtual directory in localhost was configured as **ATSWeb** but while making AJAX calls I am constructing the full URL with a different case for the virtual directory (atsweb). 
Since the ADFS cookie was set with the path /ATSWeb, while doing the AJAX call the browser is not sending the Fedauth cookie to the server. This is leading to all sorts of issues.

You can read more about cookie paths at the links below.
http://www.allbacktomine.com/blog/2009/02/04/BrowserCookiesThePathIsCaseSensitive.aspx

[Why are cookie paths case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399982/why-are-cookie-paths-case-sensitive)